# ¿Cómo puedo evitar tener caracteres repetidos en un string?

Tags: javascript

Estuve resolviendo esto con una función que tiene 2 parámetros `(s,r)`; s, es el *string* y `r`, el numero que indica cuantas veces se puede repetir

Ejemplo: si ingreso `asdf("aass",1)` me tiene que dar `as`

El código que estoy intentando hacer:

```
function asdf(s, r) {
  let resultado = [];

  s.forEach(function(element, index) {
    if (element === s[index + r - 1]) {
      for (let i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        resultado.push(element);
      }
    }
    console.log(resultado);
  });
}

asdf(["a", "a","a","a", "c"], 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu intento no funciona, en primer lugar porque cuando comparas el elemento actual `element` con el elemento en la posición `index + r - 1` puedes acceder a índices más allá del tamaño del arreglo lo cual es inválido.

Una solución es ir contando cuantos caracteres de cierto tipo has insertado hasta el momento, si en un determinado instante, esta cantidad es mayor que `r`, entonces simplemente no insertas ese carácter a la respuesta. Esta solución, a parte, garantiza el orden relativo de la salida con respecto a la entrada, que me imagino es algo que deseas.

Una estructura de datos útil en este ejercicio es un HashMap, la cual es una estructura asociativa que permite guardar pares de llaves y valores. En este caso la llave sería el carácter, y el valor la cantidad de veces que hemos visto este carácter. Javascript tiene una implementación [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) de la misma. (Convendría mirar si es compatible con el ambiente en el que deseas ejecutar el código)

```js
function repetidos(s, r) {
  let resultado = []; // Arreglo donde se guardará el resultado
  let mapa = new Map(); // Un mapa para contar los caracteres que hemos visto hasta cierto momento

  // Se itera por cada elemento del arreglo (entrada) 
  s.forEach(function(element, index) {
    // Si este carácter ya ha ha sido insertado en el mapa, incrementamos en uno el valor asociado
    if (mapa.get(element)) {
      mapa.set(element, mapa.get(element) + 1);
    } else {
      // Si no lo habíamos visto, esta es la primera instancia de ese carácter que vemos
      mapa.set(element, 1);
    }
    // Siempre y cuando hayamos visto menos o r cantidad de este carácter, lo insertamos en la respuesta
    if (mapa.get(element) <= r) {
      resultado.push(element);
    }
  });

  return resultado;
}

let res = repetidos(["a", "a", "s", "s"], 1);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Me encanto la solución, pero no funciona si pongo 
"a","a","b","a","a","a"     la 2da vez que aparece "a" , no lo reconoce

Comment: disculpa por si no lo aclare

Comment: Quieres decir que no se pueden repetir los caracteres contiguos?

Comment: lo que trato de decir que esta bien la mayor parte,
repetidos(["a", "a", "s", "s"], 1); esto nos da= "a,s"
esta bien 
pero si ponemos en tu codigo (["a", "a", "s", "s","a"], 1) (una "a"al final), nos da "a,s" otravez y nos tiene que dar "a,s,a"

Answer (score 1):

**Una sola vez**

Podrías dividir ([`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) el *string* y usar [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), de manera que obtenemos los elementos únicos, finalmente, usamos [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) y lo devolvemos

```js
function unique(s) {
  if (Array.isArray(s)) s = s.join("")
  // Comprobar si es array, y hacer join() para unirlo
  return [...new Set(s.split(""))].join("");
  // Set nos da un elemento tipo Set, no array
  // Con los tres puntos lo vamos a convertir a un array y usaremos join() para unir todo el array
}

console.log(unique("aaaa")) // a
console.log(unique(["a","a","a","a"])) // a
```

---

**Varias veces**

Podrías usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para obtener cuántos elementos específicos hay dentro de el resultado, si son menores que el número máximo de veces, añadiremos un elemento al resultado, finalmente devolveremos el resultado

```js
function unique(s,r) {
  if (Array.isArray(s)) s = s.join("")
  const filtered = []; // Definir el resultado
  s.split("").forEach(w => { // Procesar cada letra del string
    if (filtered.filter(t => t === w).length < r) { // Usar filter
      filtered.push(w); // Si existen elementos menores al máximo, añadir la letra actual
    }
  });
  return filtered.join(""); // Devolver el resultado
}

console.log(unique("aaaac", 2)); // aac
console.log(unique("aaaac", 3)); // aaac
console.log(unique("aaaac", 1)); // ac
console.log(unique(["a","a","a","a"], 2)) // aa
```

**Opción 2**

Puedes obtener todos los elementos duplicados, e irlos eliminando uno por uno hasta que quede la cantidad máxima, eliminar todos los elementos duplicados del string y concatenarlos con el array de los repetidos ya modificado a los elementos máximos

```js
function unique(s,r) {
  if (Array.isArray(s)) s = s.join(""); // Comprobar si es array y unirlo
  if ((typeof s === "string") === false) return; // Si el elemento no es un string, detener la ejecución de la función
  let repeated = []; // Definir elementos repetidos
  const split = s.split(""); // Dividir el string
  split.forEach(el => { // Recorrer cada letra
    if (split.filter(w => w === el).length > 1) { // Comprobar si hay más de un elemento en el array devuelto por filter
      repeated.push(split.filter(w => w === el)); // Añadir un nuevo elemento a repeated
    }
  });
  repeated = Array.from(new Set(repeated.map(JSON.stringify))).map(JSON.parse); // Obtener los arrays únicos
  // console.log(repeated);
  s = [...new Set(s.split(""))].join(""); // Obtener un string con solo letras únicas
  repeated.forEach(el => { // Recorrer repeated
    s = s.replace(el[0], ""); // Reemplazar el elemento actual para no tener letras de el array repetido
    while(el.length > r) {
      el.splice(0, true); // Eliminar el primer elemento
    }
  });
  s += repeated.flat().join("");
  return s;
}

console.log(unique("aaa", 1)); // a
console.log(unique("aaa", 2)); // aa
console.log(unique(["a","a","b","a","a","a"], 2)); // baa
console.log(unique(["a","a","b","a","a","a"], 1)); // ba
```

Comment: Me encanto la solución, pero no funciona si pongo "a","a","b","a","a","a" la 2da vez que aparece "a" , no lo reconoce

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una respuesta más sencilla de entender que cumple con lo que buscas realizar. Solo es cuestión de leer cada instrucción.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     function asdf(s, r){

       var anterior = "";
       var cant_repetido = 1;
       var resultado = [];

       for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){

         if(anterior == s[i]){

            cant_repetido += 1;             
                
         }else{                 

            anterior = s[i];  
            cant_repetido = 1;                  
         }  

        if(cant_repetido == r ){

         for(var j = 0; j < r; j++){
            resultado.push(s[i]);
         }                   
    }               

    }//for

    console.log(resultado);

 }//cierre función
 
 //Para obtener solo 1 caracter de cada secuencia
 console.log( asdf(["a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s", "a", "a","b","a"], 1) ); //["a", "s", "a", "b", "a"]
 
 //Para obtener 2 caracteres de cada secuencia si es que cuenta con 2
 console.log( asdf(["a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s", "a", "a","b","a"], 2) );//["a", "a", "s", "s", "a", "a"]
 
 //Para obtener 3 caracteres de cada secuencia si es que cuenta con 3
 console.log( asdf(["a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s", "a", "a","b","a"], 3) );//["a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s"]
 
 //Tu ejemplo que buscabas lograr 
 console.log( asdf(["a", "a", "s", "s", "a"], 1) );//["a", "s", "a"]
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```